# How to get the _current_ duration of a video with FFMPEG? (Not meta)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec

I tried ffmpeg -i myfile, while myfile is partially downloaded. FFMPEG gives me the whole file duration, not of the downloaded part. Can I see this with FFMPEG or another tool?

**Answer:**

With MediaInfo.

Answer (score 1):

With MediaInfo

## [sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo)

### Note

Shameless copy/paste from the question